# Why the point SS is at lower potential than S in the MOSFET circuit?

Tags: transistors, fet

I can't understand why the p type(SS) and the n type conductor(S) are said to be in reverse bais.

[image]

Comment: Diode current flows from p to n. This means that the voltage applied to the n drain will reverse bias the drain-substrate junction (n to p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substrate (SS) is at the same potential as the source (S). So the junction has zero bias and is actually not reverse biased.

It would be better to call it something like "not forward biased".